# Custom listview, error when setText

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, nullpointerexception

I have created a custom listview. It has a image, text and a checkbox and when I try to set a value for the above I get a NUll Pointer Exception. How ever if I don't set a value I get the default list...why is this happening?

```
class PInfo {
    String appname = "";
    String pname = "";
    String versionName = "";
    int versionCode = 0;
    int icon;
 }

 public class InstalledApps extends Activity{

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ListView listview;
private Activity activity;

List<PInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PInfo>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.applist);

    activity = this;
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for(ApplicationInfo app : packages) {

        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = (String) app.loadLabel(pm);
            newInfo.pname = app.packageName;

        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1){             
            installedApps.add(newInfo);

        } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            installedApps.add(newInfo);

        } else {

            installedApps.add(newInfo); 
        }
    }

    InstalledAppsAdapter iap = new InstalledAppsAdapter(this, installedApps);
listview.setAdapter(iap);

}
}

   class InstalledAppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
List<PInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
ListView listview; 

public InstalledAppsAdapter(Activity a, List<PInfo> b) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    installedApps = b;
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listview = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return installedApps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View customView = arg1;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(arg1 == null){
        customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);


    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.iv = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.tv = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.cb = (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)customView.getTag();
    }

    PInfo pinfo = installedApps.get(arg0);

    holder.tv.setText(""+pinfo.appname);

    return customView;
}

static class ViewHolder{

    ImageView iv;
    CheckBox cb;
    TextView tv;

}
```

}

EDIT : aded the full source

It looks like as if findViewById(R.id.textView1) is returning null..why??

Comment: Post your Logcat output and the full implementation of the Adapter, as well as how you are using it. Also, post the layout `listrow.xml`.

Comment: simply you can check by passing static string in settext as `holder.tv.setText(""+"test");` is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use ****"textView1"****named id in anyother ui. Change the id name of the TextView and use it.

Check this code

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    View  customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent,false);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView tv= (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CheckBox cb= (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


    PInfo pinfo = installedApps.get(arg0);
   tv.setText(""+pinfo.appname);//If u comment this line it works

    return customView;
}
```

Use this code instead of that. May it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrouding that line with a null check. This should do the trick,

```
if(holder.tv!=null)
 {
 holder.tv.setText(""+pinfo.appname);
 }
```

This won't cause any harm to the logic.

Comment: But if you see the settext there, it is something like, ""+pinfo.appname this, which means if pinfo is null his textView will print a empty space. It won't crash.

Comment: it is going to print a empty space in the TextView since he uses string concatenation right? Shouldn't be a problem. The problem arises only when the TextView object is null. I have faced the same situation sometimes and this worked for me without any flaw.

Comment: If `appname` is not a static field it will also throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: If appname is not static this should work, ryt? holder.tv.setText(""+"test");

Comment: r u sure the TextView id in listrow is "textView1" ?.

Comment: I changed the TextView id to textView2..n added the whole code, btw every time holder.tv is NULL..

Comment: can you add this line  holder.tv = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); before setText and try?

Comment: how abt adding this line   holder = new ViewHolder(); on top of both the lines I told previously in my comment?

Comment: Hmm..I marked the above as the answer, cus it would give a clear solution to anyone how come across it..